# GPUMp4Composer is Muting my video, when app is running on my phnone(android 10). But it is working fine in Emulator(android 9)

Tags: android, android-studio, video, ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am using GPUMp4Composer for adding two things:
-Filter
-Watermark

Both the things are working correctly in the emulator (android 9).
But the resulted video from GPUMp4Composer does not have any sound (muted) when I am using the app on my phone (android 10).

This is my code:

```
    Bitmap watermark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.watermark);
    new GPUMp4Composer(srcMp4Path, destMp4Path)
        .size(540, 960)
        .videoBitrate((int) (0.25 * 16 * 540 * 960))
        .filter(new GlFilterGroup(FilterType.createGlFilter(filterTypes.get(select_postion), getApplicationContext())))
        .filter(new GlWatermarkFilter(watermark))
        .mute(false)
        .listener(new GPUMp4Composer.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(double progress) {

                Log.d("resp",""+(int) (progress*100));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

                Log.i("watermark & filter","Completed");
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onCanceled() {

                Log.d("resp", "onCanceled");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(Exception exception) {

                Log.d("resp",exception.toString());

            }
        })
        .start();
```

This only happens when I merge audio(aac file) with my video and remove the original video.